# Inheriting from Base Class C#

Tags: c#

Not sure what i'm doing wrong but are Properties not directly inherited from a base class. If there is:

```
public class Fruit{
   string[] GroupFruit{get;set;}

   public Fruit()
   {
   }
}

public class Citrus : Fruit{
    GroupFruit = new string[]{"lemon", "lime", "orange"}

   public Citrus()
   {
   }
}
```

I don't seem to be able to set GroupFruit in the Citrus class.
Thanks.

Jerome

Comment: That's because your `GroupFruit` property is private, which is the default access for class members.

Comment: And you can't assign inherited members like that. Instead of saying "I don't seem to be able", please read [ask] and include the full error messages you get - including your research for them.

Comment: But the first problem is that you wrote that initialization code _outside of a method_. Make the property in the base class `protected` or `public` and move the initialization code in `Citrus` into the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize it in the constructor of the child class and it must be at least `protected`:

```
public class Fruit
{
    protected string[] GroupFruit { get; set; }

    public Fruit()
    {
    }
}

public class Citrus : Fruit
{

    public Citrus()
    {
        base.GroupFruit = new string[] {"lemon", "lime", "orange"};
    }
}
```

Comment: You also can pass values to base class constructor and keep property private (or better use field for that). Or you can remove empty constructor from base class